# how ask browser if audio device allowed and then if video allowed?

Tags: audio, video, permissions, getusermedia

I got some fails on the way to solve it.

So I think it's worth to share my solution.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-wfvqpl

Answer (score 0):

```
      try {
        await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
           audio:true,
        });
        log('audio is permited');
        try {
          let stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            audio:true,
            video:true
          });
          log('video and audio is permited');

        } catch (e) {

           log('video is not permited');
        }

      } catch (e) {
        let videoConstraint = false;
      }
```